# Google Places api not returning anything

Tags: ios, mkmapview, google-places-api

I am trying to display results from Google Places on my MKMapView. The code is getting called to retrieve the data, but it logs nothing. I don't think the problem is with the annotations being added because in the log, it returns `Google Data: (
)` without anything in it. How would I fix this. Here is the code I am using -

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    //Get the east and west points on the map so you can calculate the distance (zoom level) of the current map view.
    MKMapRect mRect = self.schoolMap.visibleMapRect;
    MKMapPoint eastMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMinX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));
    MKMapPoint westMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));

    //Set your current distance instance variable.
    currenDist = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(eastMapPoint, westMapPoint);

    //Set your current center point on the map instance variable.
    currentCentre = self.schoolMap.centerCoordinate;
}

-(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType {

    CLLocation *userLoc = self.schoolMap.userLocation.location;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = userLoc.coordinate;
    //Change the 9000!!
    // Build the url string to send to Google. NOTE: The kGOOGLE_API_KEY is a constant that should contain your own API key that you obtain from Google. See this link for more info:
    // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", currentCentre.latitude, currentCentre.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currenDist], googleType, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];

    //Formulate the string as a URL object.
    NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

    // Retrieve the results of the URL.
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    //The results from Google will be an array obtained from the NSDictionary object with the key "results".
    NSArray* places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];

    //Write out the data to the console.
    NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", places);
    [self plotPositions:places];
}

-(void)plotPositions:(NSArray *)data {
    // 1 - Remove any existing custom annotations but not the user location blue dot.
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in self.schoolMap.annotations) {
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPoint class]]) {
            [self.schoolMap removeAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    }
    // 2 - Loop through the array of places returned from the Google API.
    for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i++) {
        //Retrieve the NSDictionary object in each index of the array.
        NSDictionary* place = [data objectAtIndex:i];
        // 3 - There is a specific NSDictionary object that gives us the location info.
        NSDictionary *geo = [place objectForKey:@"geometry"];
        // Get the lat and long for the location.
        NSDictionary *loc = [geo objectForKey:@"location"];
        // 4 - Get your name and address info for adding to a pin.
        NSString *name=[place objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *vicinity=[place objectForKey:@"vicinity"];
        // Create a special variable to hold this coordinate info.
        CLLocationCoordinate2D placeCoord;
        // Set the lat and long.
        placeCoord.latitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        placeCoord.longitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
        // 5 - Create a new annotation.
        MapPoint *placeObject = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithName:name address:vicinity coordinate:placeCoord];
        [self.schoolMap addAnnotation:placeObject];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I call 'getting nowhere'

Comment: can you share the exact url params you are sending up in the query?

Comment: "I am trying to display results from Google Places on my MKMapView" Don't do that. If you have Google data you must show it on Google maps, it's in their terms and conditions.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing with an MKMapView without Google Places then @Craig

Comment: Sure, you can display all sorts of results on MKMapView, you've just got to find a source that lets you. Or switch to using Google's map element https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map